# how to enable @Preview for kotlin desktop compose demo project?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I downloaded the [demo project](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/tree/master/examples/codeviewer) to study kotlin compose.

I try to add @Preview on a @Composable fun, but get warn that: **Unresolved reference: Preview**

I add `implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.1.1")` in `kotlin.sourceSets.named("CommonMain").dependencies` in [build.gradlw.kts](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/blob/master/examples/codeviewer/build.gradle.kts):

```
        named("commonMain") {
            dependencies {
                api(compose.runtime)
                api(compose.foundation)
                api(compose.material)
                api(compose.materialIconsExtended)
                implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.1.1")
            }
        }
```

But still get **Unresolved reference: Preview** error.

I use IDEA 2021.3.3, Build #IU-213.7172.25, built on March 16, 2022.

Comment: Have you imported the annotation `import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview`? Also have you tried Android Studio? It seems preview works only in AS according to docs

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to import `androidx.compose.desktop.ui.tooling.preview.Preview` to preview in desktop.

Go to Settings > Plugins > search in the marketplace for **Compose Multiplatform IDE Support** and Install this plugin.

After that, you can use Preview annotation and it will import the correct lib.

Comment: This answer should be accepted as the right one.

Answer (score 13):

First of all, we need to understand that we are creating our composables or views into the `commonMain` into the shared module. So, we can’t specify to the IDE which platform we need to preview. This should be your folder structure.

```kotlin
|- sharedModule
    |- androidMain
    |- desktopMain
    |- commonMain
        |- composables
```

Then we need to create the previews into each platform we’ll need as following.

1. Add ui preview tooling dependency for each `sourceSet` we want to preview.

```kotlin
val compose_version = "1.4.1"

val commonMain by getting {
    dependencies {
        // we don't need add anything in here
    }
}

val desktopMain by getting {
    dependencies {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:${compose_version}")
    }
}

val androidMain by getting {
    dependencies {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:${compose_version}")
    }
}
```

2. Add your preview into the specific sourceSet module.

   We imagine that we have a MyComposable view.

   ```kotlin
   // commonMain/composables/MyComposable.kt
   @Composable
   fun MyComposable() {
       Text(text = "Hello there!")
   }
   ```

   Now, we need to create our preview into the needed preview sourceSet platform module.

   ```kotlin
   // androidMain/previews/MyComposablePreview.kt

   @Composable
   @Preview // now we are able to call the preview annotation
   fun MyComposablePreview() {
       MyComposable()
   }
   ```

   And we can add for desktop for example if needed.

   ```kotlin
   // desktopMain/previews/MyComposablePreview.kt

   @Composable
   @Preview
   fun MyComposablePreview() {
       MyComposable()
   }
   ```

   Your files should look like this.

   ```kotlin
   |- sharedModule
       |- commonMain
           |- composables
               |- MyComposable.kt
       |- desktopMain
           |- previews
               |- MyComposablePreview.kt
       |- androidMain
           |- previews
               |- MyComposablePreview.kt
   ```

   And that’s it! Hope it be helpful.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer imho. As you stated, the important thing is, that you do not put your previews in the `commonMain` directory, but e.g. in `androidMain`.

Comment: how can we do it for ios ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Roman,

As of now 2024.Jan, we just need to install plugin [Compose Multiplatform IDE Support](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16541-compose-multiplatform-ide-support).

And then you will see compose ICON next to the @preview function
[image]

Comment: Thanks, Linden; I have installed the plugin, but the compose icon doesn't show up... I AS broke so I'm using AS Preview